# oracle database connection in java

Tags: java

I am new to java and i have written the following:

```
package mypackage;
public class DBconnection {

     Connection con = null;

    public Connection getConnection() throws Exception, SQLException
    {
        try
        {
             Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
             con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@zzz:1521:zzz","zzz", "zzz");
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {

        }
        return con;
    }

    public void removeConnection() throws SQLException
    {
        con.close();
    }

}
```

When I am accesing the above code in a jsp page i have written following:

```
   DBconnection dbconnect = new DBconnection();   
   dbconnect.getConnection();
```

I want to erite dbconnect.con.prepareStatement......("sql query here");// but error is coming as **con is not public in mypackage.DBconnection ; cannot be accessed outside package**

dbconnect.con is not accessible why????? I have declared variable con in public in the above code. Error is coming as con is not public in mypackage.DBconnection ; cannot be accessed outside package, how to resolve this??? please help me

Comment: i have already added import in jsp page as : <%@page import="mypackage.DBconnection"%>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code posted above, `con` is package visible and not public. That is why you get the message `cannot be accessed outside package`. To make it public you have to write

```
public Connection con = null;
```

Note that if you are just going to call

```
dbconnect.con.prepareStatement
```

you might end up with a `NullPointerException`, since `con` is only initialized in the `getConnection()` method. So I would advise to use the getter you created

```
dbconnect.getConnection().prepareStatement
```

Of course, the getter would need to be adjusted to only create a new connection when `con` is still `null`. Otherwise it can just return `con` directly. The `removeConnection` should then after closing the connection set `con` to `null`, otherwise calling the `getConnection` after calling `removeConnection` would return a closed connection, which is pretty useless

Comment: ok then if i will write like dbconnect.getConnection().prepareStatement("sql query here"); //then to close database connection i will write: dbconnect.getConnection().close();// will it close the connection properly??

Comment: Not with the current implementation of getConnection, since this always returns a new connection object. Hence you would not close your old connection but a new connection

Comment: i did not get you my friend can you please elaborate this by writing some code please?

Comment: ys of course i will write: dbconnect.removeConnection(); after dbconnect.con.prepareStatement("sql query"); but if i will write dbconnect.removeConnection(); after dbconnect.getConnection().prepareStatement the will it close the connection properly??

Answer (score -1):

move this code to the constructor

```
public DBconnection(){
try
    {
         Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
         con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@zzz:1521:zzz","zzz", "zzz");
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {

    }
}
```

then make one object of it and share it to all your application classes and when you want to use `connection` just call `getConnecion()` from his object